# Msi secure property

Tags: wix, windows-installer, merge-module

In wix project, I have a property "MyProperty" contained in a fragment in a file "FileContainingMyPropery.wxs". I want to use that property in both the merge module and the msi of the project:

[image]

But since [SecureCustomProperties are not merged from MergeModule](http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/bugs/2295/), I cannot mark my property as Secure...

The purpose of the property is to store the path to which some components are deployed to. The value of the property is set by querying the registry:

```
<Property Id="MY_PROPERTY" Secure="no">
        <RegistrySearch Id="ProductSignature" Root="HKLM" Win64="no"
                        Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyProduct\MyVersion" Name="PathName" Type="directory">
        </RegistrySearch>
  </Property>
```

Is it ok to set this property as not secure?

Answer (score 0):

If the property is used in the execute sequence of the MSI then it needs to be marked secure, because that's what SecureCustomProperties is about.

Can't you add it to the list in the MSI before you build? Assuming of course that you use the property in the Execute sequeunce.